# Any website to search for foods high in a particular nutrient?

Tags: nutrition, resources

USDA.gov has removed their Food Composition Database through which you were able to search for list of foods high in particular nutrient, such as potassium, vitamin C, etc., and their new [Food Data Central](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/) does not enable that.

I know that NutritionData has [Nutrients in Food Tool](https://nutritiondata.self.com/tools/nutrient-search), but I'm missing search per serving and search through shortened (not full) lists.

So, does anyone know for another useful database?

OK, USDA has such lists [Nutrient Lists from Standard Reference Legacy (2018)](https://www.nal.usda.gov/fnic/nutrient-lists-standard-reference-legacy-2018) in pdfs, but I'm still looking for other options (free and not mobile apps).

Answer (score 5):

Hm, I've found something similar to the old USDA.gov nutrient search:

**[Canada Nutrient File](https://food-nutrition.canada.ca/cnf-fce/newNutrientSearch-nouvelleRechercheAliment.do)** - you can search by a nutrient or food and it gives reasonable results (you can narrow it down to food groups) and you can see all foods on a single page, for example, search for fructose (limited to fruits/juices) gives 97 foods.

**[Australian Food Composition Database](https://www.foodstandards.gov.au/science/monitoringnutrients/afcd/Pages/nutrientssearch.aspx)** is extremely detailed: you can search by **249 nutrients,** including the ones you can rarely search on internet, such as organic acids (acetic, citric acid...), fiber (stachyose, inulin...), all fatty acids, all amino acids...

Comment: These are both excellent resources! Great finds.

Answer (score 3):

The [Cronometer](https://cronometer.com/) website can perform this kind of search for foods high in a specific nutrient, but only if you're paying for the [Gold Account](https://cronometer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028026971-Subscription-Types) upgrade. The feature is called the [nutrient oracle](https://cronometer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018510531).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the [Nutrients in Food Tool](https://nutritiondata.self.com/tools/nutrient-search) at nutritiondata.self.com.

I've used it in the past to generate an ordered list of foods that contain the most Methionine and Lysine to create my [Methionine + Lysine Complete Protein Cheat Sheet](https://green.michaelaltfield.net/2011/02/12/the-methionine-lysene-complete-protein-cheat-sheet/).

You can simply choose a nutrient, and it will show you a list of foods that are highest in it **based on levels per 100g serving**. For example, here's the results for the vegetables highest in Iron per 100g:

- https://nutritiondata.self.com/foods-011119000000000000000-w.html?maxCount=28